# iPhone SDK 4 - How to programmatically detect volume hardware button press?

Tags: iphone, button, hardware, volume

How would you detect if the user presses the volume hardware buttons and prevent default behaviour?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unforutanely, I don't have an answer, but be careful - most reasons for wanting to know when those buttons are pressed aren't good reasons and will get your app rejected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` (or alternatively [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons))

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to prevent the default system behaviour?

Comment: @dan - Apple does not allow you to override system behavior of buttons like that. There was an app that got in trouble recently for changing the behavior to take a picture instead.

Comment: @ghills - Thanks, I've read about this. But I don't need app store approval. It must work on my dev device, only.

Comment: I want to emphasize that this is a private API call that will result in app store rejection, in case anyone comes by and sees the upvotes & marked answered on this answer.

Comment: FYI, this notification also won't differentiate between hardware button presses and software on screen volume changes.