# Detect when volume button is pressed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, sdk

I've done lots of research and I know that Apple will not allow this but does anyone have code or can someone point me to code that enables me to detect when a user presses either the up or down volume button on the iphone?

I need to be able to detect which one is pressed (up or down). I will not be submitting anything to apple that has this code.  I am just wondering if possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it-- look at these --

[program access to iPhone volume buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons)

[iPhone SDK 4 - How to programmatically detect volume hardware button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722239/iphone-sdk-4-how-to-programmatically-detect-volume-hardware-button-press)

[How to get audio volume level, and volume changed notifications on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651252/how-to-get-audio-volume-level-and-volume-changed-notifications-on-ios-4)