# use volume button as input control in ios

Tags: ios, iphone

I want to use volume button as a Start/Stop button in my own app. As far as I know there is only third party camera app that is able to use volume button as the control.

My question is, can it work on other type of app beside camera app? Will Apple reject my app if I am using volume button as a control/input?

Is there any Apple Documentation that state those restriction?

Answer (score 1):

Look at AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification.

See: [iPhone SDK 4 - How to programmatically detect volume hardware button press?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722239/iphone-sdk-4-how-to-programmatically-detect-volume-hardware-button-press)
**or**

[program access to iPhone volume buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons) **or**

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/outputVolume

for all I know it isn't private anymore after iOS 3.0

Comment: which means i can use whatever i want with the volume button?

Comment: I did some more research on this. Seems like Apple could reject it, but the rules aren't clear of what is possible or not