# How to customize MPVolumeView?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, audio-streaming

I have tried many methods to implement a regular `UISlider` and control the device volume, but it's all Native-C functions which results in many untraceable bugs.

I tried the `MPVolumeView` it works like charm, it even controls the device volume even after you close the app, just like the iPod app.

My question is, is there anyway to customize the `MPVolumeView` with specific colors and images, just like `UISlider`?

NOTE: I want a legal method without using private undocumented APIs.

**UPDATE**
As per @Alexsander Akers answer, since the sub views are hidden in `MPVolumeView` I had to cycle through subviews, get the `UISlider` and customize it, here is the code.

```
IBOutlet UISlider *volumeSlider;   //defined in <class.h> and connected to a UISlider in Interface Builder

-(void) viewDidLoad {
     ....
     [self setCustomSlider];
     ....
}

-(void) setCustomSlider{
     MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:[volumeSlider frame]] autorelease];
     NSArray *tempArray = volumeView.subviews;

     for (id current in tempArray){
           if ([current isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]){
                    UISlider *tempSlider = (UISlider *) current;
                    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trackImage.png"];
                    img = [img stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5.0 topCapHeight:0];
                    [tempSlider setMinimumTrackImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                    [tempSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

           } 
    }
    [volumeSlider removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:volumeView];
 }
```

Comment: Well done.  Nice job updating your question.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was this accepted in the App Store?

Comment: @sooper very late reply, sorry. Unfortunately, I didn't continue this app and never submitted it to App Store. But from personal experience, I have seen many tutorials of modifying the original components and they were accepted.

Comment: Note that in iOS 6, there are built-in methods for customizing the MPVolumeView slider, similar to the methods for UISlider

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try cycling through its subviews and look for a UISlider subclass?

Comment: In the end that's exactly what I used, Just for clarity I will update the question with the code.  I hope Apple don't reject the app for that.

Answer (score 8):

Since **iOS 5.0** you can use **[UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)** on a **UISlider**, even when part of **MPVolumeView**.

Anywhere in your codebase:

```
[[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPVolumeView class], nil] setMinimumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nowplaying_bar_full.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 25, 5, 25)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPVolumeView class], nil] setMaximumTrackImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nowplaying_bar_empty.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 25, 5, 25)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MPVolumeView class], nil] setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nowplaying_player_nob.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here a list of some of the other classes that can be implemented using UIAppearance:
https://gist.github.com/mattt/5135521

Comment: Working on iOS 8 perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

There are now ways to accomplish this, simply use:

```
– setMaximumVolumeSliderImage:forState:
– setMinimumVolumeSliderImage:forState:
– setVolumeThumbImage:forState:
```

Which are slightly different method names than the ones for the vanilla `UISlider`.

This prevents you from having to cycle through the views and potentially have something break in the future as Apple changes things.

Answer (score 1):

Answer in Swift:

```
func customSlider() {
        let temp = mpVolView.subviews
        for current in temp {
            if current.isKind(of: UISlider.self) {
                let tempSlider = current as! UISlider
                tempSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = .yellow
                tempSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = .blue
            }
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try using a [Notification](http://webbuilders.wordpress.com/2009/04/19/objective-c-troublesome-mpvolumeview/), but it looks like [Apple is denying them.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons)

---

[EDIT]

[Try this](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2008/12/mpvolumeview-demo-project.html).