# How to detect if a volume button was pressed?

Tags: iphone, ios, volume

I am making a game and when the volume (+) gets pressed I would like to increase a int by one. I can do this with a button, but how would I do this with a volume button?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458438/ios-use-the-volume-buttons-as-input. That should be helpful.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8397170/how-to-implement-a-volume-key-shutter-for-iphone

Comment: and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528443/iphone-detect-volume-keys-press

Comment: Thanks! They are helpful.