# How can I execute a method when the volume button is pressed?

Tags: ios, audio, volume, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to execute a method when the user presses the volume button but the "volumeChanged" line does not appear in the logs. I looked at several examples

[iPhone Detect Volume Keys press.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528443/iphone-detect-volume-keys-press)

[iOS Detect system volume level change. private API or not? AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25308589/ios-detect-system-volume-level-change-private-api-or-not-avsystemcontroller-sy)

```
-(void)volumeChanged{
    //do something
    NSLog(@"volumeChanged");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    masterViewController = self;
    [masterViewController swipeInit];
    [masterViewController intervalPickerInit];

    // init audio session
    AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    AudioSessionSetActive(true);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(volumeChanged:)
                                             name:@"AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: I think the signature for your selector is wrong. You're calling @selector(volumeChanged:) and the method you wrote is @selector(volumeChanged) without a colon.

Comment: I have tried removing the colon and it still does not trigger volumeChanged.