# How can I detect volume change while screen is off in iOS?

Tags: ios, background, volume, avaudiosession

I have code that detects volume change when the app is running in the foreground. But I want to detect volume change in the background and when the screen is off.

```
AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];        
[audioSession setActive:YES error:nil]; // Start Audio Session
[audioSession addObserver:self  //observer for the audio session
               forKeyPath:@"outputVolume"
                  options:0
                  context:nil];
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqual:@"outputVolume"]) {
        NSLog(@"volume changed!");
    }
}
```

Here is my log output when I press volume while app is in foreground.

```
2015-06-23 08:54:44.523 MayDay[469:71914] volume changed!
```

Comment: please check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528443/iphone-detect-volume-keys-press

Comment: I actually did look at that before. AudioSessionInitialize is actually deprecated in ios7.

Comment: ow but check what is the API replace with AudioSessionInitialize might be you can do withi this.

Comment: The one in my code example AVAudioSession

Comment: try to make there Notification that will be called i guess

Comment: Is there a way to register the observeValueForKeyPath as a background process?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81293/discussion-between-jack-shultz-and-nitin-gohel).