# Changing Volume with UIButton

Tags: iphone, xcode, slider, volume, ipod

I have seen countless tutorials on how to change the iPhone volume with a slider, button my application needs the volume be changed via two buttons, one up, one down. Here is my code:

```
    - (IBAction)volumeUp:(id)sender
    {
        [[musicPlayer setVolume:["current volume???" + 0.1]];
    }

    - (IBAction)volumeDown:(id)sender
    {
        [[musicPlayer setVolume:["current volume???" - 0.1]];
    }
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)volumeUp:(id)sender
{
    [[musicPlayer setVolume:musicPlayer.volume+0.1];
}

- (IBAction)volumeDown:(id)sender
{
    [[musicPlayer setVolume:musicPlayer.volume-0.1];
}
```