# Are you able to launch an app from hardware press in iOS?

Tags: ios, button, volume, launch

I'm saying that with the app not running (fresh boot, or stopped), is there a way for me to program it to start running after some hardware button combo-press? (ex. "Volume+" 3 times, "Home" 3 times.)

Second Part:

What about if the app had been run, but then put into the background, and the phone was locked; would a hardware button combo-press work to have the app do anything?

Essentially I'm exploring ways to discreetly communicate with an app via hardware buttons without requiring the User to view the screen. (ex. In the pocket)

Answer (score 0):

This might be possible on jail broken devices using private APIs but it's definitely not possible on regular devices with an App Store app.

The only way to launch an app is for the user to select it or for another app to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not without a jailbreak. If you do jailbreak take a look at Activator and/or Keycommands in Cydia.

Answer (score 0):

[You do not have access to the main button on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435415/catching-hardware-buttons-on-ios-when-my-app-is-in-background).  That's reserved for Apple's use only.

[You might be able to use notifications to detect when volume buttons are pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons).